# Set start_url in web app manifest based on the URL that was added to homescreen

Tags: progressive-web-apps

My site has several subsections. When a user adds the site to their homescreen, I'd like to make sure that the home screen icon launches them into the subsection they were on when they added to homescreen.

I can register a different manifest for each subsection, but this doesn't work for single page apps where there's no page reload. I'm considering storing the subsection in a cookie and then redirecting from a generic start URL based on that cookie.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried implementing your suggestion? Also check if deeplinking can help you with this.

Answer (score 4):

If you **remove** the `start_url` from the **manifest.json** file then it will default to the page user was browsing while adding pwa app to homescreen.
ref : https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/manifest-contains-start_url

Comment: This works, but then you won't get the "Add to Home Screen" popup, as the start_url is one of the requirements.

Comment: And the next bad thing is, that the manifest is invalid when you check it with the chrome tools

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the web app manifest url when the user navigates between different subsections?

```
document.querySelector('link[rel=manifest]').href = '/example-manifest.json';
```

Comment: anyone tried this?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is for each page do you have a separated manifest with attribute start_url specific to each page.

Editing:
in the HTML for /your_path:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/path/to/your_path-manifest.json">
```

in the HTML for other pages:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/path/to/any_other_page-manifest.json">
```

Comment: did someone try that? Can you elaborate how to do multiple manifests for each route? Where would I put those manifests (for example im using a SPA with react)

Comment: @dcts If you have full control over the HTML for /your_path and for all other pages, you can include <link rel="manifest" href="/path/to/your_path-manifest.json"> in the HTML for /your_path, and <link rel="manifest" href="/path/to/user-manifest.json"> in the HTML for other pages.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem just now. Here is my solution:

I completely removed the manifest tag from the initial HTML. Instead I now put the manifest together entirely in JS with the `start_url` set to `window.location.href`. Then I add it to the `head` as a Base64 data URL:

```js
const manifest = {
  name: 'My App',
  short_name: 'My App',
  display: 'standalone',
  theme_color: '#ffffff',
  background_color: '#ffffff',
  icons: [
    { src: `${window.location.origin}/path/to/icon.png`, sizes: '192x192', type: 'image/png' },
    { src: `${window.location.origin}/path/to/icon.png`, sizes: '512x512', type: 'image/png' },
    { src: `${window.location.origin}/path/to/icon.png`, sizes: '192x192', type: 'image/png', purpose: 'maskable' },
    { src: `${window.location.origin}/path/to/icon.png`, sizes: '512x512', type: 'image/png', purpose: 'maskable' }
  ],
  start_url: window.location.href
};

const link = document.createElement('link');
link.rel = 'manifest';
link.href = `data:application/json;base64,${btoa(JSON.stringify(manifest))}`;
document.head.appendChild(link);
```

Seems to work on both Android and iOS.

**Note:** Since data URLs don't have a root you cannot specify any root-relative URLs within the manifest (e.g. for icons). But it's easy to fix by prepending with `window.location.origin`. Also the `start_url` may not be relative. E.g. using just `window.location.pathname` doesn't work, that's why I am using `window.location.href`.

**Note 2:** If you are using a tool to autogenerate the PWA support of your app make sure this tool doesn't generate its own manifest during the build. Usually there should be a config option to disable this. For the Vite PWA Plugin I was able to configure `manifest: false`.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and tried messing about with the start_url applying many suggestions and none worked. What did work is to remove start_url all together.

Now I'm able to go to any page under and subdirectory and save the page to my phone home screen, when clicking on the save link I taken to the correct page.

Tested this in Chrome, Safari, Firefox and Edge.

Hope that helps.