# Set PWA start_url in web app manifest based on the URL that was added to homescreen

Tags: progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I would like to make the start_url in the manifest at the where user visit the landing page.
https://example.com/1234
https://example.com/4321

this is my php to fetch whole url {{ Request::fullUrl() }}
I put at "start_url" : "{{ Request::fullUrl() }}", it doesn't fetch in json file.

I had try change the manifest.json to manifest.php, but don't know how to convert the json content into php to make it work.

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/_manifest.php?start_url=val" data-pwa-version="set_in_manifest_and_pwa_js">
```

I know this is old question and I search all over the internet still can't find the solution.
[Set start_url in web app manifest based on the URL that was added to homescreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39495573/set-start-url-in-web-app-manifest-based-on-the-url-that-was-added-to-homescreen)
this doesn't have a solution. delete the start_url doesn't make the PWA work.

Any expert could help me? Appreciate!
I'm newbie on coding, please forgive my limited knowledge.

Answer (score 5):

Chrome (and most other browsers) require you provide the `start_url` in the manifest, and it can't be dynamic.

You could build this behaviour by saving the page the user was on when the PWA was installed. Then, set the `start_url` to a simple redirect page that checks to see what page the user was on when they installed, and redirect them to that page.

To save the page the user is on when the PWA is installed, listen for the `appinstalled` event, then save the page to localStorage:

```js
window.addEventListener('appinstalled', () => {
  localStorage['installedFrom'] = window.location.pathname;
});
```

Then, in the redirect page, do something like:

```js
const installedFrom = localStorage['installedFrom'];
if (installedFrom) {
  window.location.replace(installedFrom);
} else {
  // No install page saved, send them to the home page?
}
```

Comment: what if user clears browser cache?